# Python Code - "FileNotFoundError"

Tags: python

Can someone tell me what is wrong with my code. I am a noob and new to programming.

```
myFile = open('example2.txt', 'rt')
total=0.0
count=1
for line in myFile:
    total=total+float(line)
    count=count+1
    print("reading in:"+line,end='')

average=total/count
print("\n\nAverage: "+str(average))
```

Comment: Little more information wouldn't hurt, what are you trying to do? what problems are you encountering? etc

Comment: please post the traceback

Comment: @JohnKugelman Oh yeah? The more you know ;P

Comment: @JohnKugelman Good idea ;P

Comment: I just ran this code in Python 3, and everything works correctly.  What is happening for you?

Comment: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'example2.txt'

Comment: I am trying to find the average

Comment: check your text file! Is it in the same place as your python file ?
by the way set count=0

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that `example2.txt` is not located in the current working directory when you run the script.

In general, it's a good idea to identify files with the entire path to the file so you know exactly where your script will look for the file:

```
 open(r'C:\TestProgram\Sample Data\example2.txt', 'rt)
```

Alternatively, if your goal is to write a program that will run in the current working directory, test for the presence of expected files before trying to open them.